# Can Panpsychism be reconsidered through computer science?

Tags: philosophy-of-computer-science, panpsychism, abstract-object

This is a topic that dates at least as far as Descartes.  It may be new in natural science.  The term may be a neologism, but not the concept.

Lets assume that everything from the subatomic particle to the star is an object (in object-oriented computer science terms, that is, an object is has properties, data and methods), could it then be deeply nested in other objects and share some global properties, data and methods?  Is whole and part a property of said object?

It could also be an active object that dynamically changes its data, or it could be a static copy of similar quadrillions of objects (that only have a potential to become active and living objects).

Would these premises support the panpsychiatric view, that mind is a necessary element of reality?

Comment: What does being an object have to do with panpsychism? Anyway, think about this: in a computer game, there may be a fluid dynamics finite element simulation of water, and the water has waves but does not have any "wave objects" in the computer science sense. The waves are an emergent phenomenon of the finite element model, not something that has an explicit existence in the program.

Comment: @causative - The waves consist of water molecules. In the computer game, each molecule of water could potentially be an object (for really sophisticated fluid dynamics simulator). Then, most likely, all water molecule objects will be an exact copy. But! In an even more sophisticated computer simulator, each water molecule has a potential to have a mind of its own.

Comment: The molecules would be objects, but the *wave* would not be an object.

Comment: @causative - The human mind is considered a wave of electrical signals. Then, to follow your logic, you would have to conclude that our mind is not an object, only billions of neurons are.

Comment: I was clear to specify earlier that I am talking about objects in the *computer science* sense. In reality, a wave is an object, but in a fluid dynamics computer program it is not what computer programmers would call an object. What we can take from this is that the real-world notion of an object is different from the computer-programming notion of an object.

Comment: @causative - I think being an object with clear distinction and boundaries - is a potential, not a quality.  In computer game - you can go from 1 object (background image) to thousands of objects with distinct properties and behavior.

Comment: This is really indirect but I understand that your user profile and name alludes to the fictional work of The Matrix and I am assuming that your question stems from this very work, but may I bring forth some thoughts on what I think maybe the central motivation for the movie, partially because of the Wachowski's being influenced by philosophy during the direction and production, I personally think the core philosophy used was Plato's Allegory of the Cave I want to mention that Plato's Allegory only alludes to the 'real' world being abstracted but it doesn't necessarily self reflect and ask

Comment: ...how about the allegory being implemented on the 'real' world itself. I want to bring forth the thought that the movie the Matrix doesn't reflect on what is real after the introduction of the 'world' after the awakening that happens after the ingestion of the red pill. Just a thought! Not really an answer to your question but just a discourse to provoke thought

Comment: @Howwhye - A computer simulator has a big difference when compared to philosophy - hard limits on energy. If you program each quark to have a mind of its own, even the energy of a Big Bang would not be enough. To save energy, most of Plato's Cave is a flat image with no life or objects. Only when physicists look at the photons - they become objects.

Comment: "*When it rains, the sky doesn't get wet!*"